# iOS 8 forwarding call only when busy

Tags: ios

There is an option to forward calls to specific number, but it forwards every call made to my number. I'd like set conditional forwarding, e.g. redirect call only when I am busy or not answering.

I was not able found any solution and have only found some "special" numbers (*61 etc.)

Is it possible (without jailbreak)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would have to be set up by your phone provider

Comment: That's a carrier feature and setting. Not iOS. Ask your carrier if they make it available.